# How to handle race conditions in ModelForms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` that uses the model instance to perform a clean validation:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   text_field = forms.CharField()
   text_field_2 = forms.CharField()

   def clean_text_field(self):
       data = self.cleaned_data['text_field']
       print(self.instance.text_field_2)
       return data
```

If I set an initial instance for the form, e.g. `MyModel.objects.create(text_field='hello', text_field_2='world')`, then when using in an `UpdateView`, this works fine and `print(self.instance.text_field_2)` displays `world`.

However, if I open the form in 2 browser tabs, complete the form on the second tab and then try to complete the form on the first, `print(self.instance.text_field_2)` returns `None`.

The error seems to be because on the submissoin of the second form, the form.save() is called twice - the second time with no instance, even if the sessions are completely different.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You don't return anything from `clean_text_field` so you set `text_field` to `None` on the first submit, the second submit is getting the value you saved

Comment: Sorry @IainShelvington I don't follow? This is just a basic example where 2 users are using the same form at once. It shouldn't matter if nothing is returned, but I have corrected the code; the issue still persists

Comment: The return value of the field clean method overrides whatever value is submitted, when it was returning `None` that was the value saved

Comment: Thanks, I think I phrased the question poorly - please refresh edits. `text_field_2` isn't affected by the clean function on `text_field`.